# I have a Multilingual Website need to extract the url and need to check the country specific code is present

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit5

I have a ecommerce site where the URL changes based on the country language. Only 2 letters will be added based on the country ex NL for netherland,NO for Norway.

once the browser is launched i need to check which url is launched and need to proceed based on the launched url.

i am expecting if condition logic

IF url = nl
Then " "
Else if
url = NO
Then " "
else " "

As i am new to coding struggling in this logic and conditions
we are using serenity with junit 5 framework

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: We are using java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `WebDriver.getCurrentUrl()` to get the current URL as a `String`:

```
String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();

if (url.contains("NL") {
    // Proceed with Netherlands
}
else if (url.contains("NO")) {
    // Proceed with Norway
}
else...
```

The `WebDriver` instance should be injected with Serenity.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the URL with this:

```
String URL = driver.getCurrentUrl();
```

Now let's say for nl the URL will contain substring "lang=nl". If so you can simly do this:

```
String NL = "lang=nl";
if(URL.contains(NL)){
    //Do something
}else{
    //Do something else
}
```

Don't forget to put some delay before getting the current URL by `driver.getCurrentUrl()` to make page loaded

Comment: String currenturl= driver.getCurrentUrl();
        String UK=gben,NZ=nzen,SE=sesv,AU=auen,NL=nlnl,NO=nonb,IE=ieen,DK=dkda,FI=fifi;
        if (currenturl.contains(NL || NO || IE || DK || FI || SE)) {
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#ss-nav-primary__item--menu-aurora-glasses > a")).click();
        } elseif(currenturl.contains(AU)){
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#ss-nav-primary__item--menu-new-test > a")).click();
        }else {
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#ss-nav-primary__item--menu-glasses > a")).click();
        }

Comment: Well, I'm not sure about `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#ss-nav-primary__item--menu-aurora-glasses > a")).click();` etc, but the logic is something like this. Just make sure your strings like `UK=gben` are unique enough. URL can contain charachters like `nl` or `ne` inside it not only as a country indicator